# Check for multiple attribute matches in an array of objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an array of objects (they are all the same object type) and they have multiple attributes, is there a way to return a smaller array of objects where all the attributes match a test case, string, what ever that attribute type is.

Comment: Did you mean list perhaps, instead of array? The default `[]` type is a list, but the `numpy` library has arrays.

Comment: In my case and list is as good as an array, you answer below solves my immediate problem. (which I have to wait 10 minutes to accept apparently)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a list comprehension with [`all()`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all); the following presumes that a `list_of_attributes` has been predefined to enumerate what attributes you wanted to test:

```
sublist = [ob for ob in larger_list if all(getattr(ob, attr) == 'some test string' for attr in list_of_attributes)]
```

Alternatively, if your input list is large, and you only need to access the matching elements one by one, use a generator expression:

```
filtered = (ob for ob in larger_list if all(getattr(ob, attr) == 'some test string' for attr in list_of_attributes))
for match in filtered:
    # do something with match
```

or you can use the [`filter()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter):

```
filtered = filter(lambda ob: all(getattr(ob, attr) == 'some test string' for attr in list_of_attributes)
for match in filtered:
    # do something with match
```

Instead of using a pre-defined `list_of_attributes`, you could test all the attributes with the [`vars()` function](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#vars); this presumes that **all** instance attributes need to be tested:

```
all(value == 'some test string' for key, value in vars(ob))
```

Comment: This answers my question, I find it a bit slow as I have a smallish list on one side and a large list on the other (the small list is fairly large itself)